# How to use data from 1st query to check 2nd query?

Tags: mysql

Below is my 1st query where I use to get post data and creator data who creates it in post.date_created order from post and account_data_base tables.

```
SELECT post.*, account_data_base.* FROM post 
JOIN account_data_base ON post.creator_id = 
account_data_base.user_uid ORDER BY post.date_created DESC
```

and this is my 2nd query in php after running 1st query which I use to check if the post creator likes his/her post or not.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM like 
WHERE post_id = ? and userLike_Id = ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $postId, $account_data_base_id);
```

as you can see $postId and $account_data_base_id are values that I get from my 1st query. I wonder is there a way that I can combine 2 queries at once where I can get post data, creator data as well as my 2nd query to check like or not?

Update: this is what I tried but the like check doesn't show accurate info:

```
SELECT post.*, account_data_base.*, 
EXISTS(SELECt * FROM like WHERE like.post_id = post.id and like.userLike_Id = account_data_base.user_uid) FROM post 
JOIN account_data_base ON post.creator_id = 
account_data_base.user_uid ORDER BY post.date_created DESC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results really help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I think your second query in your deleted answer is a good way. You just need to use a LEFT JOIN and something like `SELECT p.*, a.*, l.post_id IS NOT NULL as likeExists`. If `like(post_id, userLike_Id)` is unique, I would prefer that solution over the EXISTS subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your EXISTS query as subquery in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT post.*, a.*, EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `like` l
    WHERE l.post_id     = p.id
      and l.userLike_Id = a.id
) as likeExists
FROM post p 
JOIN account_data_base a ON p.creator_id = a.user_uid
ORDER BY p.date_created DESC
```

This will add the field `likeExists` which is either `1` or `0`. And you don't need to run the query once per post.

Comment: There are no real booleans im MySQL. `true` and `false` are just aliases for `1` and `0`. Try out [this example](http://rextester.com/IVGOI36306)

Comment: My bad. I think your answer is correct but I still need to check before I can say 100%. BTW, can you pls explain to me how p.id and a.id values are available in EXISTS because it runs before FROM and JOIN Thanks!

Comment: @KevinVuD Logically SELECT ist the third last step (before ORDER BY and LIMIT). If I'd design SQL, I would write the queries like `FROM t SELECT c`. But I guess when SQL was designed they thought that `SELECT c FROM t` sounds more like a natural language.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your help!